# Saving api secret keys to database django

Tags: django

I want to store api keys to db as the application has subdomains and each subdomain can have individual keys, what I tried is as follows
models

```
class ExternalKeys(models.Model):
    public = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    secret = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    webhook_secret = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
```

and in views I call it as follows

```
def get_api_key():
    return HttpResponse(ExternalKeys.objects.first().secret, content_type='text/plain')

stripe.api_key = get_api_key().content.decode()
```

this prints the key in terminal, but when I send request to stripe, it throws error `Invalid API Key provided`, how I can make it work or save the keys so that end users just have to add their keys from front end, thank you